# Should a system be “uniform” to qualify for it to be in steady state?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am wondering about whether a system need to be “uniform” to qualify for it to be in steady state or can not uniform systems also act as a steady system.

Can someone please clarify this.
Thanks in advance!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steady state implies only that local thermodynamic state variables do not change in time. They can be non-constant function of position in space, e.g. there can be a temperature gradient and corresponding heat flux. If temperature function $T(x)$ does not change in time, it is a steady state.

Answer (score 1):

Steady state just means whichever state is in question doesn't change. If you pick uniformity as the state in question then it's a tautology that uniformity is required for a steady state.

If you pick virtually any other state then uniformity is not required for steady state. Suppose you pick the number of elements as the state. As long as that number stays constant then the system is in a steady state.